# facebook login button - there are two samples on the facebook site

Tags: facebook

I'm reading this documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/

sadly the documentation is confusing. The page has a code-generated button, which is very nice. However, the *actual* code the page uses is completely different -

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

I don't understand which one I'm meant to use, or how to call a js method on logging in if I use the code generated sample:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

The code sample calls "onlogin", but it is some sort of weird... facebook thing. Has anyone done login (and, honestly, with facebook's money you'd think they could write documentation! grrr!)

Comment: They should both work, they are just different versions of writing the same thing. The latter is the HTML5 compatible version. And the `onlogin` attribute works for both.

Comment: @CBroe yeh, i actually worked with it and worked that out (oops) ~ if you want some points post as an answer and i'll mark you right. Also, thanks for the HTML5 fact, I actually did not know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should both work, they are just different versions of writing the same thing. The latter is the HTML5 compatible version.

And the `onlogin` attribute works for both; it doesn’t even have to be written as data-onlogin as the rest of the parameters in the HTML5 version. I’m pretty sure Facebook parses that attribute itself (browsers don’t know a native login event), but guess they simply chose that attribute name to have it be kind of consistent with “traditional” HTML event handler attributes such as onclick etc.